# How can I access Jupyter from miniconda?

Tags: python, jupyter, miniconda

I am really new using miniconda. I created an environment in which I installed Jupyter,
but when I tried to execute the command "jupyter notebook"
I got the following message:
[image]

I don't know where the error is (I even uninstall tornado and installed its 4.5.3 version as other post suggested)...
I will be grateful if you could help me with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm, looks like some strange dependency did not get installed correctly. You could try `conda update --all` and then try to load jupyter notebook again. Or you can try creating a new environment with `conda create -n myenv python=3.8 jupyter ipython `. Sometimes jupyter does not install `ipython`, so that can cause issues too.

Comment: It looks like `parso` did not properly specify a dependency on Python. This syntax for giving types of variables is only available in Python 3.6 and later (if I recall correctly). Is there a reason you need to use Python 3.5? The current version is 3.8 and 3.9 will be released soon...

Comment: Thanks!!  I solved the problem by unsinstalling parso

Answer (score 0):

It's not downloaded by default with Miniconda. For first time use, just open the anaconda prompt and type:

```
> pip install jupyter
```

then open the notebook directly

```
> jupyter notebook
```

that's it.

Comment: I've seen others, such as [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-notebook-wont-open-via-anaconda-anymore/17924/8?u=fomightez) say that they needed `python -m notebook` to launch the notebook, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66986780/8508004).