# Error Message when trying to use pip install in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, installation, pip, jupyter-notebook

I keep getting this message appear when attempting to use pip installer in notebooks. I am not sure where to go from here.

[Example of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlRv5.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287117/jupyter-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "!" mark before the pip command:
example:

```
!pip install TensorFlow
```